# Installing a pet door - no ideal location - support beam question

Tags: wood, joists, construction, support, beam

I am in the process of installing a pet door and there really isn't any ideal area in the living area to install it due to either things on the inside that are in the way or on the outside that are in the way etc.

I found one location that would be perfect for it until I cut the drywall back and found a center stud. I did check this wall with a beam finder prior and knew it was there but I wanted to see what I was working with anyway.

This is an exterior wall that leads into the back yard but due to the beam, I am not sure how to proceed.

[image]

I found the second image online regarding a possible workaround but wanted to find out if there are any prerequisites for such process. The issue is that the holes on the right side are to the left of the beam that supports the window frame so putting in another piece of wood for the "jack" would probably come out too far and interfere with the the dog door it self.

Do I have any options for this?

[image]

Comment: Terminology - that's a stud, not a beam.

Comment: Advice provided too late: do your design plans before doing any cutting :-( .   Also: if you don't trust your stud-finder, drill a horizontal row of 1/16" holes to see which ones bring sawdust back.

Answer (score 3):

The image you provided from the internet is the typical solution. You state concern of the king stud for the window framing being too close to the exposed stud in your included photo to add an additional jack stud for the header for your dog door. The addition of a jack only narrows the opening one and a half inches. You need to determine the required rough opening for the pet door. If the rough opening is not at least 3 inches less than the current width between the two outside studs , you will need to get a smaller dog door , a smaller dog, or both! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Like the picture that you attached, It looks like you will be fine if you incorporate a pair of jack studs and a header board to allow for the insert of the doggie door. Do note, the original stud (the center of your cut drywall) does not need to be centered above the doggie door. Like below:[image: Beautiful Drawing...]